# How we seperate degree minutes second in php

Tags: php, regex

I am getting GPS  Latitude and Longitude as below using `exiftool`

```
  GPS Latitude                    : 22 deg 44' 42.36" N
  GPS Longitude                   : 75 deg 53' 33.00" E
```

I need to separate `22 deg 44' 42.36" N` into

```
22 deg

44 minutes

42.36 second
```

Sometime the formatted would be `110° 29' 01.1`

How I separate these??

Comment: split by ` ` (space)? and then remove `'`

Comment: You mean `print_r (explode(" ",$str));` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is formatted always the way you've shown, you can simply split it by space, and then do some more formatting.

```
$parts = explode(" ",$str);

$latlong['deg'] = $parts[0]." deg";
$latlong['min'] = str_replace("'","",$parts[2])." minutes";
$latlong['seconds'] = str_replace("'","",$parts[3])." seconds";

print_r($latlong);
```

Then maybe wrap that in a function and add some verification-tests (is_numeric,..)

Comment: It's working !! Can you provide this solution in REGEX!!

Comment: `$parts = preg_split('/ /', $str)`

Comment: or `preg_match("/([\d\w]*)[ ]([\d\w]*)[ ]([\d]*[']?)[ ]([\d\W]*))/", $str, $parts)`

Comment: As you can see, I'm no regex-expert.... So, I can't do all that in a one-liner as regex. maybe someone else...

Answer (score 2):

Using Regular Expressions you can do a match and replace on this one:

```
(?m)^[^:]+: *(\d+)(?: *deg|°) +(\d+)\' +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV0mS7/1)

PHP code:

```
<?php

$input = <<< STR
    GPS Latitude                    : 22 deg 44' 42.36" N
    GPS Longitude                   : 75 deg 53' 33.00" E
    GPS Longitude                   : 110° 29' 01.1
STR;

$coords = explode("\n", preg_replace('~(?m)^[^:]+: *(\d+)(?: *deg|°) +(\d+)\' +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*~', '\1 deg \2 mintues \3 seconds', $input));

var_dump($coords);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "22 deg 44 mintues 42.36 seconds"
  [1]=>
  string(31) "75 deg 53 mintues 33.00 seconds"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "110 deg 29 mintues 01.1 seconds"
}
```

Comment: I will try this solution!!

Comment: Great solution, I'm still trying to figure out that regex you've made. I didn't expect that to be possible as a one-liner....